# How do you handle an alternate create method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model where I want to be able to just get user input for one field in a form and then close the pop up window. That can be done by changing the respond_to in the create controller. However, I have another form for the same create controller where I want the default handling.

ie. The normal respond_to format is

```
   format.html { redirect_to @pre_production_meeting, notice: 'Pre Production Meeting was successfully created.' }
   format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @pre_production_meeting }
```

The alternate I want for the pop up form is

```
 format.html { redirect_to controller: 'shared', action: 'window_closer', notice: 'attachment was successfully updated.' }
 format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @pre_production_meeting }
```

I know one way I could do this is to set a variable and then choose the right respond to such as

```
if $form = '1' then 
   (first format option)
else if $form = '2' then 
   (second format option)
end
```

Would that be the best way to do it or is there a way to create another def that would function similar to the create def but with the modified format? If so, I haven't been able to figure out how you could call use a create2 method to process the form.

Comment: Chris, I, umm, I didn't understand what you're trying to do. Could you ELi5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways to do this: 1. create a new action for this different logic or 2. pass in a value in the query string.

If you pass in a value to the query string, you can then use your `if` statement.

```
if params[:form] == '1'
  format.html { redirect_to @pre_production_meeting, notice: 'Pre Production Meeting was successfully created.' }
else
  format.html { redirect_to controller: 'shared', action: 'window_closer', notice: 'attachment was successfully updated.' }
end
```

(Note: you used `$form` in your question as the variable. Since you prefixed it with `$` it is a global variable. You almost never want to use global variables in Ruby like that. They make code very difficult to understand and debug.)